# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum freezes the app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

So I have this interesting problem.

When I call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` it freezes my app and I don't know why.

So this is the code I have

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(leftImage, self,  @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(rightImage, self,  @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);

- (void)image:(UIImage *)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError  *)error contextInfo: (void *)contextInfo
{
  if (error != nil)
  {
    NSLog(@"Image Can not be saved");
  }
  else
  {
    NSLog(@"Successfully saved Image");
  }
}
```

So sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. When I remove those two lines, it never freezes. What can go wrong. I am assuming I can't see `didFinishSavingWithError` because the app freezes.

Here is the stack
[image]

Comment: Does it crash or does it freeze? You say both.

Comment: Define freezes. Do you mean the main thread blocks or something else?

Comment: @rmaddy Can't touch any buttons on the UI. Not sure if this is tied to the app, but the home button isn't responsive.

Comment: When your app freezes, click the "Pause" button in the Xcode debugger and have a look at the stack trace for the main thread. See what it was doing.

Comment: @rmaddy I got the picture. I don't have the best understanding of the stack

Comment: You need to expand the stack traces so you can see all of thread 1.

Comment: "So this is the code I have" No, it isn't. Your real code doesn't have `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` just sticking out like that all by itself. Show your real code in its real context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling this method twice in succession:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(leftImage, self,  @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(rightImage, self,  @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

But that method takes time to complete. You can't call it a second time until it has completed. That's what `didFinishSavingWithError` is for — it's so you know when it has completed, and so it is safe to call it again.

Thus, the solution is, don't call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` a second time until your `didFinishSavingWithError` has been called from the first time.